# Porque to_pure_number funciona en la hoja y en script dice que es desconocida

Tags: google-apps-script

Utilizo la funcion To_Pure_Number en la hoja y todo perfecto, pero cuando la utilizo en un script indica que no existe.

Estoy tratando de calcular un numero de turnos en un lapso de tiempo, donde hago

var numeroturnos = (horafinal-horainicial)/minutosduracionturno;

Como horafinal y horainicial estan en formato fecha trato de convertirlos a numero mediante to_pure_numero.

Answer (score 0):

Por que las funciones de la hoja de cálculo de Google sólo funcionan en la hoja de cálculo de Google, en otras palabras, Google Apps Script no puede evaluar la funciones de hoja de cálculo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Como hago?. Debo codificar la funcion to_pure_number ?

Comment: @JoseAvelinoMejiaBrito Debes usar JavaScript. Si requires mayor orientación, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar a esta una breve pero completa descripción de lo que quieres hacer incluyendo lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Trato de restar una variable que contiene un valor de tipo hora de otra.

Comment: @JoseAvelinoMejiaBrito Bien por tí. Como te mencioné en mi comentario anterior, "Si requires mayor orientación, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar a esta una breve pero completa descripción de lo que quieres hacer incluyendo lo que hayas intentado".